# JPA Named Query to JOIN Three tables

Tags: jpa, subquery, entity, named-query

I have a scenario Like this I have a table A in table A
I have two columns

card id | card number|fid
        |            |

now user will give card number i have to fetch the card Id and fid for that particular card number.
And for that fid in other table

fid|ftype|

I have to fetch the fid type
i need to get the vidtype in other table

Fid|vid|

and for that vid ineed to get the particluar commerce and region

vid|commerceid|region|

can you guys help me ?

Comment: Please, add your entities.

Comment: You mean names of entities

Comment: No. Full persistent classes with annotations.

Comment: JPQL uses CLASSES, not COLUMNS. JPQL != SQL